# joist bridge for hanging porch seating

Tags: hanging, support, span-tables, porch-swing

Want to build and hang a "bed/sofa" 64Lx32W on PT deck w/PT 7x2x10' rafters 16"oc.  Spacing of rafters wrong for hanging.  I can cut down size of the seating, but it defeats objective.  QUESTION:  can I place 4 "bridge supports" (for hanging bed @ corners) between the rafters using PT 2x4? 2x6? 2x8? along w/the appropriate hangers nailed into the rafters and ends of each 16" bridge (rafters are blocked)?  Thanks for help

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. It's a little hard to know what you mean; would you add a diagram to your question? (And, big props for [taking our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) already; few new visitors do...)

Comment: Don't see a way to add pics (missed that on the tour and in the comments). Rafters aren't positioned so I can hang bed to rafters w/o hanging chains angling off to right or left.  Vertical connect point falls in the 16"oc space between rafters.  Thinking about a bridge between rafters, like a piece of blocking attached w/ joist hangers. Q is... would these be strong enuff to support the weight of the bed.  If so, which (2x4 2x6 or 2x8) would be sufficient?  Alternatively, any other suggestions are welcome.  Perhaps bolting a 2x4 or 2x6 across bottom of the rafters and attaching the bed to it?

Comment: 7x2? Say what now? And yes, roof design does matter. It's not a question of whether you can add blocks, but whether the structure will support hundreds of extra pounds at that location.

Comment: You can't upload images until you have some reputation. Host theme somewhere else and post the links. We'll assist from there.

Comment: By the way, you probably _want_ some trapezoid in your chains, otherwise you'll have a swing instead of a sofa. Is that the intent?

Comment: The PT rafters measure approx 7"x2".  They are over the deck and hold up sheets of metal roofing to keep weather/snow off deck.  No load to speak of in summer when this relatively small bed/sofa will be used.  I'm thinking an overkill max 400# of people and 200# of bed => each corner load ~150#.  Intent is to have large soft comfortable area to snooze or gently swing - not sure purpose of trapezoids?

Comment: PT lumber is usually a lower grade I would use caution. I agree that blocking with a 4x4 would be the way to go but adding that much weight to a span could be questionable but 10’ span and the bed is 5+ it might work and I doubt there will be a better way to do it. To answer the questions the trapezoids would eliminate any swing quickly, you said after that it could be a swing so you don’t want them. 5’ over a 10’ span it might work +

Comment: Thanks, Ed... that was helpful.  4x4 it is.  Have other lumber and hangers I was hoping to use, but will get 4x4 for safety sake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would be installing 4"x4" joist hangers between the rafters and set in  pieces of 4x4 P.T. lumber. If you are hanging the bed with chains, I'd drill through the 4x4's at the appropriate spot and insert bolts with washers and nuts on top. Good luck.

Comment: I think that's exactly the type of "bridge" the OP describes. I agree, but I can't endorse this solution without knowing something about the roof design.

Comment: You're right. When the OP mentioned hangers I was thinking he was referring to whatever he was going to use to suspend the bed.. My bad.

Comment: This looks sort of like what I was thinking.  If the only summer load at each corner is around 150#, do I need 4x4's?

Comment: Why skimp? Especially if you're going to drill through it.